# Why doesnt the background cover the full html page?

Tags: html, css, mobile, frontend

So I tried everything that I know of and don't know why this isnt working please send help. 
max-width/height didnt work there is always a small gap between html and border. And if I want to style the background with a linear gardient fo example there is always a small line wether it is right or at the bottom, I only can style it with th background-color. Here is the code:

```
html{
    [![width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, black, gray);][1]][1]
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N04VV.png
```

Comment: Hello,
html{background: linear-gradient(to left, black, gray);}
should be the only thing you need to achieve this.
If you still have a white line, it may be your device simulator that creates it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background: linear-gradient(to left,black, gray );
  }
</style>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```